# GKE Beta Logging experience - JSON Parsing lost

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-logging

we log json content to STDOUT from our pods and GKE nicely sends them to stackdriver logging and it gets parsed into a jsonPayload within stackdriver logging.

when we check the  `Try the new Beta Monitoring and Logging experience` checkbox in the GKE cluster definition, the json parsing ability is lost and the log content is just taken as a textPayload with all json parsing gone.

Is this a bug - any ETA for a fix?

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the release note [fixed issue section](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/release-notes#fixed-issues_4),

> If you use Stackdriver Kubernetes Monitoring Beta with structured JSON logging, an issue with the parsing of structured JSON log entries was introduced in GKE v1.11.4-gke.12.

This is fixed by upgrading your cluster:

**GKE v1.11.6-gke.2**

You may also see the following [issue thread](https://issuetracker.google.com/121340431#comment11) or the [release guide for Stackdriver Kubernetes Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/kubernetes-engine/release-guide#beta_release_1114) for more details.